# Innodb does not accept foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

We cannot run the query below. We have another table named "person" and it has a primary key person_id. As you can see, we are trying to get this column as our (customers table's) foreign key. phpMyAdmin returns #1064 syntax error. What's going wrong here?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resort`.`customers` (
  `person_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `cid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `person_id_UNIQUE` (`cid` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `person_id_UNIQUE` (`person_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `person_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `resort`.`person` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

By the way, this query is generated by Oracle's MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the columns in the constraint definition:

```
CONSTRAINT person_id
  FOREIGN KEY ()
  REFERENCES resort.person()
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

should be:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_person_id
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
  REFERENCES resort.person (id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Now it says: "#1061 - Duplicate key name 'person_id_UNIQUE'"

Comment: Geez, just look at your SQL. That's because you have two UNIQUE definitions with the same name:  `UNIQUE INDEX person_id_UNIQUE (cid ASC)` and `UNIQUE INDEX person_id_UNIQUE (person_id ASC)`. The part right after `UNIQUE INDEX` is the name of the index.