# Foreign keys in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have made eight tables with an EER diagram in MySQL Workbench. Now I use the program's suggested SQL to create the tables. It works for most of them, but not the ones that include foreign keys. Does anyone know how to solve this? Here is the suggested code, and the error message.

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webprogrammering`.`Deltagelse` (
  `deltagelseNr` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `deltagerNr` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Arrid` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deltagelseNr`) ,
  INDEX `deltagerNr` () ,
  INDEX `Arrid` () ,
  CONSTRAINT `deltagerNr`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `webprogrammering`.`deltagere` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Arrid`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `webprogrammering`.`arrangement` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

ERROR MESSAGE LOG:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') , INDEX `Arrid` () ,
>   CONSTRAINT `deltagerNr`
>   FOREIGN KEY ()
>   REFERE' at line 6

Comment: It seems that MySQL Workbench generates invalid SQL. See this post for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430272/innodb-does-not-accept-foreign-key/10430312#10430312

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webprogrammering`.`Deltagelse` (
  `deltagelseNr` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `deltagerNr` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Arrid` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deltagelseNr`) ,
  INDEX `deltagerNrIdx` (deltagerNr) ,
  INDEX `ArridIdx` (Arrid) ,
  CONSTRAINT `deltagerNr_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (deltagerNr)
    REFERENCES `webprogrammering`.`deltagere` (referenceField)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Arrid_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (Arrid)
    REFERENCES `webprogrammering`.`arrangement` (referenceField2)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Change field names referenceField, referenceField2 to correct names.